# Sending SMS through Kannel on specific port using SMPP

Tags: kannel

I am trying to configure Kannel for sms push using SMPP protocol with an SMSC. The operator has provided specific Port along with username and password. I have gone through the Kannel user guide multiple times but couldn't find any port setting for the group "sendsms-user". SMSC provider has provided following example settings

```
Uname: smppout
pwd:  smppout
port: 9999
```

When ever I send an SMS, Kannel response is 'Queued for later delivery'. I guess Kannel tries to push SMS to SMSC on some default port. Can any help me setting the Port for sending the SMS.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are trying to connect to an SMSC on a certain port. For this you will want to use the group = smsc. It will look something like this:

```
group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = test
port = 9999
host = <IP>
smsc-username= smppout
smsc-password= smppout
system-type = "VMA"
transceiver-mode=true
```

The group "sendsms-user" is what your provider would use to enable web requests to hit it amongst other things. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You smsc group should look something like this

```
SMPP
Route-SMS
smsc-id = A
group = smsc
smsc = smpp
port = 9999
host = host.ip.address
receive-port = 9999
smsc-username = smppout
smsc-password = smppout
system-type = ""
address-range =
interface-version = 0x34
inquire-link-interval = 60
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Example complete configuration
group  = smsc
smsc   = smpp
smsc-id  = TEST-SMSC
allowed-smsc-id  = TEST-SMSC
host = X.X.X.X
port = 9999
transceiver-mode  = true
smsc-username  = smppout
smsc-password  = smppout
source-addr-ton  = 0
source-addr-npi  = 1
dest-addr-ton  = 0
dest-addr-npi  = 1
system-type  =  ""
address-range  =  ""

'Queued for later delivery' is because the smsc in not **online** which is in **reconnecting stage** , make sure smsc is in online state by checking status from http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:12000/status?password=xxxxxxx
```